# Como criar uma mapa JSON baseado em arquivo identado

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Olá, estou com um problema que é o seguinte tenho uma mapa com o seguinte formato e preciso criar um script que que converta esse mapa para um modelo de JSON especifico em python:

Modelo de mapa:

```
TELEFONIA
  + CELULAR
    + CORRETOR
      + a
        ~ CANCELAR LINHA
        ~ SOLICITAR LINHA
    ~ b
    + aba
      ~ CANCELAMENTO DE LINHA
      ~ CANCELAMENTO DE MODEM
  + CMS
    ~ ALTERAR
```

Modelo de JSON:

```
{
  "label" : "TELEFONIA",
  "valor":[
    {"label" : "CELULAR", "valor":[
      {"label" : "CORRETOR", "valor":[
        {"label" : "a", "valor":[
          {"label" : "CANCELAR LINHA" },
          {"label" : "SOLICITAR LINHA" },
        ]}
      ]},
      {"label" : "b" },
      {"label" : "aba", "valor":[
        {"label" : "CANCELAMENTO DE LINHA" },
        {"label" : "CANCELAMENTO DE MODEM" },
      ]},
    ]},
    {"label" : "CMS", "valor" :[
      {"label" : "ALTERAR" },
    ]}
  ]
}
```

Um código que fiz (Porém já apaguei bastante coisa):

```
text = 'TELEFONIA\n\t+ CELULAR\n\t\t+ CORRETOR\n\t\t\t+ a\n\t\t\t\t~ CANCELAR LINHA\n\t\t\t\t~ SOLICITAR LINHA\n\t\t~ b\n\t\t+ aba\n\t\t\t~ CANCELAMENTO DE LINHA\n\t\t\t~ CANCELAMENTO DE MODEM\n\t+ CMS\n\t\t~ ALTERAR'
nivelAnterior = 0
def createTree(text):
    e = []
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        # valor = (line.split("~ ")[1] if nivelAnterior == line.count('\t'))
        if "+" in line:
            valor = line.split("+ ")[1]
        elif "~" in line:
            valor = line.split("~ ")[1]
        else:
            valor = line
        e.append({"nivel":line.count('\t'),"valor": valor})
    return e
def a(val):
    pai = 0
    prev = 0
    listOfChild = []
    listOfObjs = []
    valuePai = ""
    i = 0
    for value in val:
        nivel = value["nivel"]
        if nivel > prev:
            # child
            pai = prev
        elif nivel == prev:
            # bro
            pai = pai
        elif nivel < prev:
            # parent
            pai += nivel - prev
        prev = nivel
        print("\nvalor atual: ",value["valor"])
        print("\t",listOfChild)
        print('\n\t',listOfObjs)
val = createTree(text)
# print(val)
a(val)
```

Comment: não entendi a lógica para ter aparecido esse `aba` no meio do JSON, e acredito que deveria ser só um `a`, não?
você precisa criar um modelo de parser, pois toda a lógica está baseada nas indentações do seu arquivo, e para saber o que está dentro do quê. 
Eu criaria uma função para fazer a criação de um nível e usar uma função recorrente, que se chama, caso apareça o + ao lado do elemento.

Comment: Mostre o que você tentou fazer até o momento, pois a ideia do Stack Overflow é ajudarmos com dúvidas de código, e não escrever o código para os outros.

Comment: @LuanNaufal, foi um erro meu mesmo corrigi

Comment: @LuanNaufal já coloquei uns do códigos que já fiz aqui

Comment: pelo que estou entendendo, quando não existe sinal de `+ ` ou `~`, entendo que a lógica é a mesma que quando aparece `+`, no caso do primeiro elemento, ou seja, ele adiciona o "valor" como próximo elemento no mesmo nível, que é uma lista. E as listas somente possuem um elemento e não mais].
A lógica não é simples, mas vou ver se arrumo um tempo para montar algo aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUÇÃO:

Depois de repensar toda lógica cheguei na seguinte solução:

```
map = open("MAPA CATEGORIAS.MAP",encoding="utf8").read()

def getListOfChild(listOfElements, fatherIndex):
    i = fatherIndex + 1
    ret = []
    for element in listOfElements:
        if listOfElements[fatherIndex].count("#") < listOfElements[i].count("#"):
            ret.append({"lineIndex":i,"label":listOfElements[i]})
        else:
            break;
        i += 1
    print("getListOfChild:",ret)
    return ret;
def getListOfExp(mapGeral,fatherIndex):
    expd = []
    i = fatherIndex
    father = {"fatherIndex":fatherIndex,"fatherLevel":mapGeral[fatherIndex].count("#")}
    map = getListOfChild(mapGeral, fatherIndex)
    for line in map:
        print(line["label"])
        print(("#"*(father["fatherLevel"]+1))+"+")
        if line["label"].startswith(("#"*(father["fatherLevel"]+1))+"+"):
            line["valor"] = getListOfExp(mapGeral,line["lineIndex"])
            expd.append(line)
        elif line["label"].startswith(("#"*(father["fatherLevel"]+1))+"~"):
            expd.append(line)
    return expd

map = map.split("\n")
print(map[1].count("#"))
open("result.json","w+",encoding="utf-8").write(str(getListOfExp(map,208)).replace('\'','"').replace('#','').replace('+ ','').replace('~ ',''))
```

ps: o código já esta linkado da forma que eu precisava lendo e escrevendo arquivos,

Obrigado pelo apoio,

Comment: Eu só não entendi de onde apareceu esse `#` que não estava na descrição inicial do seu código, @LucasAvelino. 
Eu montei uma parte do código para resolver isso, mas falta debugar o final, pois ao diminuir o nível, ele não estava printando no Json final. 
Mas se resolveu o seu problema, que ótimo!

Comment: @LuanNaufal eu estava tendo problemas de comparação de string com o \t ai decidi dar replace em todos \t, pra sanar meu problema!

Comment: ótimo! importante que conseguiu resolver. Boa sorte